# ¿Cómo recuperar datos en vista con blade y si no existe que tome un valor por defecto?

Tags: laravel, blade

lo que pasa es que necesito extraer toda la información del usuario que ha iniciado sesión, al existir campos que pueden ser nulos necesito que si no existe el valor me tome alguno por defecto pero en la vista no en la bd.

```
<div class="jornada">
                        <p class="p_perfil">Jornada:<span
                                class="span_perfil">{{ auth()->user()->jornada->nombre }}</span></p>
                    </div>
```

El problema esta en que si el usuario no tiene una jornada me lanza el siguiente error:

> Attempt to read property "nombre" on null

He investigado y se puede usar *if* con *isset*.

```
@if(isset(${{ auth()->user()->jornada->nombre }})) 
//codigo
@else
//codigo
```

Pero creo que lo estoy implementando mal:

```
<div class="jornada">
                        <p class="p_perfil">Jornada:
                                <span class="span_perfil">
                                    @if(isset(${{ auth()->user()->jornada->nombre }}))
                                        {{ auth()->user()->jornada->nombre }}
                                    @else Nada 
                                </span>
                        </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno pude solucionarlo con la ayuda de ustedes, encontré que el *isset* no me reconocía si el valor era nulo. Por lo cual tuve que implementar el operador de fusion de **`null`**.

```
<p class="p_perfil">Jornada:
    <span class="span_perfil">
        {{  auth()->user()->jornada->nombre ?? '-' }} 
    </span>
</p>
```

En este caso al ser nula la jornada toma el valor del guion.